# Logging on to server creates duplicate user profiles in Documents & Setting

Tags: windows-server-2003, user-settings

Windows Server 2003.
I am having a problem with the creation of new user profiles when logging in remotely to a terminal server. The new user profile gets added under Documents & Settings as username.domainname.

Deleting the new profile does not allow the original profile to be reverted to. Went logging on to the server again, it creates another new user profile.

Nothing was changed in the Active Directory or security settings.

How do I get the original profile to be used?

EDIT:

If found what I was looking for here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324734 
However, this fix didin'twork.  The user profile folder security was already set to Full Control.  I changed the registry ProfileImagePath from \username.domain to \username but after logging out and logging back in, a new user profile is still being created.  It won't access the original profile.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I acknowledge in advance that my answer isn't a solution, but this problem happens if the user's existing user profile is unable to be loaded.  This happens in cases where the profile wasn't closed properly when the user logged off or is locked because of an abrupt exist from a session.  Upon logon, the system attempts to open your profile ("joe") and if it fails as a result of the above, it will create an "joe.domain" profile.  This is the behavior you're seeing.

See this related question [Two user folders under documents and settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/193916/two-user-folders-under-documents-and-settings)

Comment: This is the first I am reading of this possibility. Everywhere else says is a permission problem.  Any idea's on how to "release" the profile from its locked session?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem occurs due to access rights issues or SID (Security ID issues).

I.e. can the username.domainname access the previous username profile? 
Or maybe you moved or copied the old username profiles with a tool that did not preserve the acl and ownership info?

Comment: No files were moved. No permissions changed.  Full Control is permitted to the Documents & Settings user profile folder.

Comment: In the security tab, check the list of users. Windows is picky about the settings on profiles, so compare the faulty ones with the ones that do behave.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the NTUSER.DAT file was missing from the documents & settings user folder.  I don't know where it went, but I was able to get a copy of the file from a backup.  I put the file back in it's rightful place, redid the registry edit to restore the original user profile.